# Arduino game "Stop It"

Tags: loops, button, arduino

so I am making this game "stop it" which is a game that (in my case) are 6 led's next to eachother, glowing + making a sound 1 by 1 and every time you press button 1 (knop1), when led 1 burns, the leds start blinking faster.

I have that figured out
**But I need a 2nd button (knop2) which you need to be able to press at any time to fully stop the game, but I keep failing on this.**
I have tried many things but every one of them failed
Also sorry for a somewhat complex code...

This is the code:

```
    #define NOTE_E4  330          //Declareren van de noten
    #define NOTE_G4  392
    #define NOTE_A4  440
    #define NOTE_0   000
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    int noten[] = {               //De noten
    NOTE_E4, NOTE_G4, NOTE_A4, NOTE_E4, NOTE_A4
    };
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    int duur[] = {                //de duur van elke noot
    225, 225, 950, 225, 925
    };
    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    const int buzzer = 9;         //Hier staat de pin van de buzzer voor het lied
    const int snelheid = 1.5; //Snelheid, een hoger getal laat alles trager gaan, een lager getal laat het sneller gaan

    int led1 = 2;
    int led2 = 3;
    int led3 = 4;
    int led4 = 5;
    int led5 = 6;
    int led6 = 7;
    int gluid = 9;
    int run = 0;
    int knop = 12;
    int knop2 = 11;
    int n = 220;

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    void setup() {               
      pinMode(led1, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(led3, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(led4, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(led5, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(led6, OUTPUT);
      pinMode(knop, INPUT_PULLUP); 
      Serial.begin(9600);
      Serial.println("We shall begin. \n   ");
      delay(500);
      for (int i=0;i<5;i++){                //5 staat voor het max aantal noten
      int wacht = duur[i] * (snelheid * 0.9);
      tone(buzzer,noten[i],wacht);          //tone(pin,frequentie,duur)
      delay(wacht);}                        //delay zorgt er hier voor dat de vorige noot niet word afgespeeld tijdens de vorige noot
      delay(100);
      Serial.println("Press the red button to start.");
      Serial.println("You can press the black button any time to stop.");
    }

    //----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    void loop(){
        if (n <= 10)
        {
          n = 60; 
        }

else if (n == 20) { 
Serial.begin(9600);
Serial.println("You won! Congratz!");
delay(150);
digitalWrite(led6, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led5, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
delay(150);
digitalWrite(led6, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led5, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
delay(150);
digitalWrite(led6, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led5, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
delay(150);
digitalWrite(led6, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led5, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
delay(150);
digitalWrite(led6, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led5, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led4, LOW);
digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
delay(150);
digitalWrite(led6, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led5, LOW);
digitalWrite(led4, LOW);
digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
delay(150);
digitalWrite(led6, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led5, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led4, LOW);
digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
digitalWrite(led1, LOW);  
delay(150);
digitalWrite(led6, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led5, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
digitalWrite(led1, LOW);  
delay(150);
digitalWrite(led6, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led5, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
digitalWrite(led1, LOW);  
delay(150);
digitalWrite(led6, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led5, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led1, LOW);  
delay(150);
digitalWrite(led6, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led5, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
delay(150);
digitalWrite(led6, LOW);
digitalWrite(led5, LOW);
digitalWrite(led4, LOW);
digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
n = 10;
digitalWrite(led6, LOW);
digitalWrite(led5, LOW);
digitalWrite(led4, LOW);
digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
digitalWrite(buzzer, LOW);
digitalWrite(gluid, LOW);
n = 220;
delay(500);
}
else
  if(digitalRead(knop) == LOW)
  {

     if(run == 0){    
      run = 255;
      Serial.println("Next stage.");
      n = n - 20; }

     else{
      run = 0;
         }
       }
  if(run > 0)

  {
     {
      digitalWrite(led6, HIGH);
      delay(n);
      digitalWrite(led6, LOW);
      delay(n); 
      tone(gluid, 700);
    }
    {
      digitalWrite(led5, HIGH);
      delay(n);
      digitalWrite(led5, LOW);
      delay(n);
      tone(gluid, 900);
    }
    {
      digitalWrite(led4, HIGH);
      delay(n);
      digitalWrite(led4, LOW);
      delay(n);
      tone(gluid, 700);
    }
    {
      digitalWrite(led3, HIGH);
      delay(n);
      digitalWrite(led3, LOW);
      delay(n);
      tone(gluid, 900);
    }
    {
      digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
      delay(n);
      digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
      delay(n);
      tone(gluid, 700);
    }
    {
      digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
      delay(n);
      digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
      delay(n);
      tone(gluid, 600); 
    }      
  }
}
```

Comment: Don't use `delay`.

Comment: Should I use milis or micros then?

Answer (score 1):

The key is to re-organize your code into a state machine.  Remember that `loop()` is going to be called over and over.  Each time it's called, you should check what the current state of the game is and, depending on the inputs, change to the next state and return.

To illustrate, I'll use a much simpler game.  Press the start button to make one LED blink until the stop button is pressed.

```
// The WRONG WAY
void loop() {
    while (digitalRead(knop1) == HIGH) {}  // wait for start button
    while (digitalRead(knop2) == HIGH) {
        digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
        delay(250);
        digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
        delay(250);
    }
}
```

The code above is like your code in that you try to do (almost) everything on each call to `loop()`.  This makes it hard to watch for inputs.  For example, notice how we check the stop button only after each complete blink cycle.  This means the response time might not be very good (and, in fact, if the user presses and releases the button very quickly, we might miss it altogether).

A state machine approach uses a global variable or two to keep track of what the game should be doing right now.  At each point, we check the state and the inputs to determine if we need to change our state.

```
// The BETTER WAY
enum { stopped, blink_on, blink_off } state = stopped;
unsigned long target = 0;

void loop() {
    switch (state) {
        case stopped:
            if (digitalRead(knop1) == LOW) {
                digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
                state = blink_on;
                target = millis() + 250;
            }
            break;
        case blink_on:
            if (digitalRead(knop2) == LOW) {
                digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
                state = stopped;
            } else if (millis() >= target) {
                digitalWrite(led1, LOW);
                state = blink_off;
                target = millis() + 250;
            }
            break;
        case blink_off:
            if (digitalRead(knop2) == LOW) {
                state = stopped;
            } else if (millis() >= target) {
                digitalWrite(led1, HIGH);
                state = blink_on;
                target = millis() + 250;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

There are other ways to organize state machine code, but they're basically equivalent.  For example, you might decide to check the inputs before checking the state.  You might also want to factor out the transitions to eliminate the duplicate code.  I haven't done those things in this sample, because I want to make it clear how a state machine works in general.

Once you have your code organized as a state machine, it's relatively easy to respond to any input at any time.

Comment: Hmm Thank you, I4m looking into this but so far not the desired result

Comment: After alot of experimenting I came out that the `case stopped` won't keep continueing it's loop, unless if i press the first button again (knop1).
And when I try doing the speedun when you press the button when led6 is lit it doesn't work either, I'm sorry if I sound really stupid xD
This is kinda new to me